# Arguments in @functions

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am making a self function to change te text displayed by the cursor in my GUI figure. This is what I have done by the time:

```
dcm=datacursormode(hAxes.figure);
datacursormode on
set(dcm,'update',@myfunction)




function output_txt = runnumber(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
%getCursorInfo(dcm)
%inputDrDataCell

% Get the handle to the data cursor.
menu = findall(get(gcf,'Children'),'Type','uicontextmenu');
menuCallback = get(menu,'Callback');
dataCursor = menuCallback{2};

% Get the coordinates if a datatip exists.
info = getCursorInfo(dataCursor);
if ~isempty(info)
number = info.DataIndex   
end
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)],...
['Run number:',num2str(number)]};

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
%if length(pos) > 2
 %   output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];

%end
end
```

However, I would like to pass more input arguments to @myfunction in order to display the name of the axis, the raw data file etc. 
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional arguments are supplied to callbacks by using a function handle and the additional arguments in a cell:

```
set(dcm,'update',{@myfunction,arg3,arg4});
```

These correspond to the third and fourth inputs to your function:

```
function output_txt = runnumber(obj,event_obj,arg3,arg4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, nothing wrong with Hugh Nolan's answer, is to use an anonymous function handle like so:

```
set(dcm, 'update', @(obj,event) runnumber(obj,event,arg3,arg4));
```

HTH!